# Checking if an input is a digit and converting to an ascii character in C?

Tags: c

Currently stuck on a uni problem. (Language is C)

The prompt is the following:
Create a program that
reads a single input character from the terminal
checks if the input character is a digit and, if so, converts it into the corresponding integer (use the property of the ASCII values above)
prints the value of the integer as an octal number (use the %o specifier in the argument of printf) or the text "the input is not a digit" if the user has entered a non-digit character, e.g. 'q', '$' or 'Z'.

My code is the following:

```
int valueOfDigit(){
    char c;
    int i;
    c = getchar();
    i = c;
    if (c <= '9' && c >= '1'){
        printf("%o", (int) i);
    }
    else printf("the input is not a digit\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Im failing the tests as i'm printing the ascii values and not octal. What am i doing wrong? We are not allowed to use any fancy methods either.

Comment: Note that `getchar()` returns an `int`. Take the habit of storing the return value to an `int` variable. It's never wrong and often required for correct functioning of your code.

Comment: Do you have the usual homework restrictions that the most obviously useful functions cannot be used?

Comment: Note that `0` is a decimal digit, too.

Comment: You were told to mind ASCII code values. You really should. Casting an `'9'` to int ignores that hint.

Comment: @Yunnosch yes unfortunately. its a shame because with methods it would be really easy.

Comment: I imagine that the property of ASCII values to which the prompt refers is that the codes for the decimal digits are consecutive and in order, from `'0'` through `'9'`.  The prompt is giving you a *hint* with that, not just an instruction.

Comment: @Yunnosch how should i handle the ascii values in that case?

Comment: Note also that that's not just a property of ASCII.  It is a required property of the execution character set for every C program, in every environment, even when that character set is not ASCII-compatible.

Comment: At SO the normal way to indicate that your problem was solved is to accept the answer that helped most. Please do not edit your question to include something like "[SOLVED]", "(FIXED)" or similar. The fact that there is an accepted answer already serves for that purpose.

Comment: Start by looking them up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does not work, because you are trying to print a char as an int (and by it I mean you are trying to print '6' as 6). The problem is, that the chars are already ints in C(as you've noticed they're encoded using ASCII standard). To do it simply, and by that I mean not checking anything related to program safety at all, you just have to do the following:

```
if (c <= '9' && c >= '0'){
        printf("%o", (int)(i - '0'));
    }
```

This will print the int number that corresponds to your number in ASCII minus ASCII zero number, which will result in actual number being printed, for example 6 in ASCII is 54 so minus '0' which is 48 you get 6. That's the general idea.

Comment: Are you aware of https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions ? You might want to make a conscious decision on that topic.

Comment: I think your code should fail about 10% of tests. Read the comments on the question....

Comment: If you think this works, try with input "0".

Comment: @Yunnosch i missed that one, i edited the code already. As i said its the most basic form of code that i could think of.

Comment: @Gerhardh I've done so, i was trying to find a "fixed button" new to posting here. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the whole point of your homework.

When you type in a character like '6', the program receives 8 bits whose value is 00110110. This is the ASCII code for '6'.

On another hand, the binary value for the number 6 is 110 (which means 1x2<sup>2</sup> + 1x2<sup>1</sup> + 0x2<sup>0</sup>, it is stored with zeros for unused higher-valued bits, e.g. 0000000000000110 on a 16-bits CPU.

We observe that the character '6'=00110110 ends with the same bits as the integer 6=110, and in the ASCII code this is the case for all numbers between 0 and 9.

So, to convert from '6' to integer 6, you just have to drop the high-order bits. Now we observe that following this ASCII rule, the character '0' is coded as 00110000, and that is precisely what we must remove from 00110110 to obtain the number 6. This explains the `i - '0'` part in the accepted answer.

The printf formats "%o", "%d", "%x", take an integer value like 0000000000000110 and generates the ASCII sequence of characters which are displayable on a screen/console/sheet of paper/whatever. In our example the output is one byte '6' = binary 00110110. If the input was '8' = binary 00111000, the integer value is 8 = binary 1000 and the printf output is 2 bytes, the first being '1' = 00110001 and the second being '0' = 00111000; because the displayed octal form of the value 8 is "10" = 1x8<sup>1</sup> + 0x8<sup>0</sup>.